# Google Play Console - Game App restriction in specific countries

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games, playing-cards

We have uploaded our game app at Google Play successfully. When we tried to upload a second version, we noticed that our app has been restricted in our country. When we investigated we receieved a message from support team stating that the app indicates gambling and that it doesnt match the ranking of "All Ages". We have got a review from IARC stating that we are not having any issues or relation to gambling.

We contacted support again to resolve the issue, but they stated the following:
"The app contain simulated gambling, or games of chance or skill that are conducive to gambling are prohibited in the above locale"

We have done all necessary measures and took the extra mile and change UX to remove any indication to gambling though it doesnt have at the first place. We are suffering from poor communication with support team, and need a super fast fix. Any Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is nearly unsolvable problem, I've faced this and after more than 1 year of appeals with Google I couldn't convince them that my app does not contain any gambling.

Once they flag your app as a gambling app it is very hard to change it.